# Error message building Xamarin ipad app

Tags: ipad, xamarin

Error executing tool ..\bin\actool: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Xamarin.IOS.Common.targets.

Getting the error above trying to build an app in Xamarin for the iPad.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on a new iOS project, after only adding an icon set. I found that I had inadvertently removed the contents.json document from the project; once I replaced this artifact, the project build was successful.

This may or may not be your exact problem, but I would look at a clean project and compare to see if any necessary resources have been removed.